# How to aggregate annual crime count by using pandas crosstab?

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing regression analysis on Chicago crime data and I want to do aggregation on annual crime count for each region. I know Chicago crime data is pretty big but it can be publicly accessible to understand the data. Now what I did that total crime count for each region along 5 years period, but I just what to see annual crime count for each region, I am only interested in top 5 crimes.

**data**

here is the Chicago crime data on keggle: [chicago crime data](https://www.kaggle.com/currie32/crimes-in-chicago)

**what I did**:

```
crimes_2012 = pd.read_csv('Chicago_Crimes_2012_to_2017.csv', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False)
crimes_2012.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Case Number', 'Date'], inplace=True)
crimes_2012.drop(['Unnamed: 0','Case Number','IUCR','FBI Code','Updated On',
                  'X Coordinate','Y Coordinate'], inplace = True, axis = 1)
crimes_2012 = crimes_2012.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any')
```

here is what I did for total crime count for each region:

```
df=crimes_2012[['Primary Type', 'Location Description', 'Community Area']]
crime_catg = df.groupby(['Community Name', 'Primary Type'])['Primary Type'].count().unstack()
crime_catg = crime_catg[['THEFT','BATTERY', 'CRIMINAL DAMAGE', 'NARCOTICS', 'ASSAULT']]
```

**desired output**:

I want to get annual count for per crime type for each region/Community Area. something like this:

[image]

Is there any convenient way to do this easily? I tried pandas' crosstab but didn't get the correct output actually. How to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could create the desired crosstab. Couple of gotcha's, first you'll need to cast column `'Date'` as a datetime type. Then we'll filter a subset of the `crimes_2012` frame to just include the 5 crimes you're interested in with [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).

Finally, create the [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to get the desired shape.

```
crimes_2012['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(crimes_2012['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

top_5_crimes = ['THEFT','BATTERY', 'CRIMINAL DAMAGE', 'NARCOTICS', 'ASSAULT']

df = crimes_2012[crimes_2012['Primary Type'].isin(top_5_crimes)]

df_cross = (pd.crosstab(index=df['Community Area'],
                        columns=[df['Date'].dt.year, df['Primary Type']])
            .sort_index(axis=1, level=[1, 0]))
```

Then if you need to flatten the column levels, use:

```
df_cross.columns = ['{} {}'.format(crime, year) for year, crime in df_cross.columns]
```

[out]

```
print(df_cross.head())

                ASSAULT 2012  ASSAULT 2013  ASSAULT 2014  ASSAULT 2015  \
Community Area                                                           
0.0                        0             0             0             0   
1.0                      340           303           257           234   
2.0                      254           225           201           166   
3.0                      244           277           210           233   
4.0                      124           111            85            99   

                ASSAULT 2016  BATTERY 2012  BATTERY 2013  BATTERY 2014  \
Community Area                                                           
0.0                        0             0             0             0   
1.0                      227           991           866           776   
2.0                      198           658           669           574   
3.0                      241           736           667           593   
4.0                       93           354           352           319   

                BATTERY 2015  BATTERY 2016  ...  NARCOTICS 2012  \
Community Area                              ...                   
0.0                        0             0  ...               0   
1.0                      666           724  ...             485   
2.0                      544           534  ...             230   
3.0                      661           653  ...             735   
4.0                      288           288  ...             111   

                NARCOTICS 2013  NARCOTICS 2014  NARCOTICS 2015  \
Community Area                                                   
0.0                          0               0               0   
1.0                        362             278             205   
2.0                        216             173             157   
3.0                        482             519             271   
4.0                         61             102              78   

                NARCOTICS 2016  THEFT 2012  THEFT 2013  THEFT 2014  \
Community Area                                                       
0.0                          0           0           0           0   
1.0                         79        1043        1004         811   
2.0                         79         976         991         794   
3.0                        100        1338        1134         952   
4.0                         36         691         689         507   

                THEFT 2015  THEFT 2016  
Community Area                          
0.0                      0           0  
1.0                    845         851  
2.0                    669         694  
3.0                    879         968  
4.0                    499         514
```